# Block a friend of Facebook from the console of javascript in the browser

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have this variable on my console of Javascript

```
var f = "https://www.facebook.com/friend.test"
```

So, how can I block it from the console of Javascript? Is this possible?

I have one idea:

> I can go to the page where facebook block people and then do
>    `document.getElementById("u_bs_2")`; but I don't know how to send the variable f as parameter, any hint?

Answer (score 0):

IDs are generated dynamically on Facebook; you can't count on them to be consistent. Targeting the associated `<form>` by its action URL is best.

Theoretically, you should be able to set the `.value` of the form's text input to your URL, then programatically submit the form:

```
document.querySelector('form[action="/ajax/privacy/block_dispatcher/"] input[type="text"]').value = f;
document.querySelector('form[action="/ajax/privacy/block_dispatcher/"]').submit();
```